# need help to install Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, nokogiri, selenium-webdriver

I am using `Ubuntu13.04`. I have installed `Ruby2.0` using `RVM`. But now looking for any guideline to install `nokogiri` and `selenium-webdriver`. But not found any concrete step by step instructions to install the same using `RVM`. can anyone out there help me.

I have installed Ruby using the [`link`](https://gist.github.com/pcjpcj2/5443017) as follows:

> sudo apt-get -y install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core 
>   zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev \
>   libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison
>
> \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enabled
>
> echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
>
> source ~/.bash_profile
>
> rvm install 2.0.0-p0
>
> rvm use --default 2.0.0-p0
>
> ruby -v
>
> gem install rails --pre

When I used below got error:

```
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$ sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt libxslt-dev
[sudo] password for kirti: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libxslt1-dev' instead of 'libxslt-dev'
E: Unable to locate package libxslt
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$
```

Thanks

Comment: What happened when you `gem install nokogiri`?  Some output of that would be great.

Comment: That Gist seems to have most if not all of the dependencies likely to be required, try "sudo gem install nokogiri"

Comment: With RVM, you do not use sudo, unless he installed RVM as root, which is generally frowned upon

Comment: Don't point us to a link for information to answer your question. Summarize the content of that link, reducing it to only the essential data needed, and put it in your question, otherwise, *WHEN* that link dies your question will be worthless. In addition, by putting in the link you assume we are going to chase down the information to help you, but instead, what usually happens is we go look at another question where someone gave us all the information we need. You have to take the time to give us the data we need to help you.

Comment: +1 @Eugene, using RVM with `sudo` is generally going to end badly.

Comment: What errors did you receive when you tried installing the drivers and prerequisites prior to trying to install Nokogiri? RVM tells you everything you need to install for a successful Ruby installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Finally I am done using below:*

```
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$ sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libxml2-dev is already the newest version.
libxslt1-dev is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  vim-runtime
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$ gem install nokogiri
Fetching: nokogiri-1.5.9.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.5.9
Parsing documentation for nokogiri-1.5.9
unable to convert "\x90" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so, skipping
Installing ri documentation for nokogiri-1.5.9
1 gem installed

kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$ irb
2.0.0p0 :001 > require 'nokogiri'
 => true 
2.0.0p0 :002 >
```